# Настройка отображение итема в QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно чтобы в QTreeView каждый итем отображался примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е, нужно чтобы за первой иконкой был расположен текст, если текст не вмещается в оставшуюся длину итема, то нужно ставить многоточие, сразу после текста должно влезть второе изображение.

Я сделал так:

```
void TreeDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& a_option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem option = a_option;
    QString displayText = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

    QPixmap icon;
    QPixmap mark;

    ...

    painter->save();

    int itemWidth = option.rect.width();
    int itemHeight = option.rect.height();
    int itemX = option.rect.x();
    int itemY = option.rect.y();

    int iconWidth = icon.rect().width();
    int iconHeight = icon.rect().height();

    int markWidth = mark.rect().width();
    int markHeight = mark.rect().height();


    //icon
    {
        int targetX = itemX + 2;
        int targetY = itemY + (itemHeight - iconHeight) / 2;
        QRect targetRect( targetX, targetY, iconWidth, iconHeight );
        drawDecoration( painter, option, targetRect, icon );
    }

    //text
    {
       int targetX = (itemX + 2) + iconWidth + (2);
       int targetY = option.rect.y();
       int width = 100; //Длинна текста
       int height = option.rect.height();
       QRect targetRect( targetX, targetY, width, height );
       drawDisplay( painter, option, targetRect, "fasdfsdfsdfsadfsdfasd");
    }



    //mark
    {
        int targetX = (itemX + 2) + iconWidth + (2) + 100 + 2;
        qreal targetY = itemY + (itemHeight - markHeight) / 2;
        QRect targetRect( targetX, targetY, markWidth, markHeight );
        drawDecoration( painter, option, targetRect, mark );
    }



    drawFocus( painter, option, option.rect );
}
```

Проблема в том, что у меня размер прямоугольника, в котором располагается текст, - фиксирован. А нужно его как-то рассчитать чтобы использовать всю длину итема.

Второй момент: `TreeDelegate` наследуется от `QItemDelegate`, а если будет нужно наследоваться от `QStyledItemDelegate`. Там функций `drawDecoration` и `drawDisplay` нет. Или нужно все вручную делать с помощью `QPainter`?

Нельзя ли этот элемент в дизайнере нарисовать, а в коде только текст и иконки задавать?

Comment: можно сделать 2 столбца, ограничить размер первого, и вставлять вторую иконку во второй столбец

Comment: можно использовать QTreeWidget и вставлять собственные виджеты в него через setItemWidget()

Comment: Да, можно конечно, но мне кажется это не совсем правильно. Второй столбец увеличит количество элементов в два раза, соответственно, в два раза увеличится количество вызовов методов в модели. А по поводу QTreeWidget: это подходит для простых случаев. View-Model гораздо гибче

Comment: Тогда может вам поможет QRect QFontMetrics::boundingRect(const QString & text)

Comment: а что у вас длина итема? В общем случае можно расчитать размер текста, размер иконок и вывести ровно столько текста сколько надо, вот только вопрос, откуда модель будет знать размер итема?

Comment: @goldstar_labs размер итема известен,  это QStyleOptionViewItem::rect